# Including gems in a rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm trying to write a rakefile outside of a rails project.

I've created a new directory, added a rakefile and set a basic default task. It works.

I want to use the [premailer gem](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/) so in my default task I've added this -

```
premailer = Premailer.new('http://localhost/email.html', :warn_level => Premailer::Warnings::SAFE)
```

This doesn't work, I get the following error.

```
uninitialized constant Object::Premailer
```

How do I refer to the premailer gem in my task? Should I be including it in a gemfile of sorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work without a Gemfile like this:

```
require 'rubygems' # only needed for ruby 1.8.7
require 'premailer'

desc "My Task"
task :my_task do
  ..
  premailer = Premailer.new(...)
  ...
end
```

or with a Gemfile:

```
require 'rubygems' # only needed for ruby 1.8.7
require 'bundler'

Bundler.setup
Bundler.require

desc "My Task"
task :my_task do
  ..
  premailer = Premailer.new(...)
  ...
end
```

I hope this helps.